# Work-Energy Principle Derivation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, differentiation, calculus

I am currently in Mechanics I and both my professor and my book have derived the work principle in this way and I even asked about its derivation during class, but it has me puzzled.

[image]

I don't understand how they justify $$d(v.v)/dt = 2v.v' .$$ I'm assuming they take the $m$ out as a constant and but if they are taking the derivative with respect to time how does the 2 come in. Further more where does the half come from in 4.1.4. I recognize the$ (1/2) mv,$ but why wouldn't it be $(1/2) mv^2?$ I would appreciate any insight, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Do you know how to take the derivative of a product? Do that and you will find the 2. It's not a physics thing; it's a math thing.

Comment: You realize that $v^2$ and $\bf v\cdot v$ are the same thing yes?

Comment: Indeed, that is true that the dot product of v and v would be 2v. and indeed the derivative of 2v would be 2. it was the v dotted with dv/dt (the second v is a v with a dot on top indicating derivative that confused me) that's why it confused me.

Comment: Note that the derivative of 2v with respect to v is 2, but the derivative with respect to time is $2\dot v$.

Comment: Thankyou, I think that's what I was missing that the 2v(dot) represents the derivative with respect to time.

Comment: No worries. Good luck with your studies.